# Stackdriver logging agent not working and not sending to the logging

Tags: logging, stackdriver

I'm using Google Stackdriver Logging Agent v1-19 agent in one of the windows VM.

When I checked the logging it showed like this "fluentd worker is now stopping worker=0".

So according to the document [1], I thought to make sure the stackdriver is running and will test the message, But the message did not send to logging and the last log looks like this "fluentd worker is now stopping worker=0".

But there is another VM in a different project with same "Google Stackdriver Logging Agent v1-19 agent" , There the logs were moving to the logging.

Can you help me out what will be the solution.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/logging/troubleshooting#windows-instance

I tried yesterday, Need information about "fluentd worker is now stopping worker=0" and how can I make the agent work. It's just stuck.

Comment: Reboot. Then check the Windows Event Log for errors starting the service.